# Using Bootstrap modal for product thumbnails

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use the Bootstrap modal feature in my app to view a thumbnails from a carousel in more detail using the code

> /product_details.php?id=12486

with the id=12486 obviously being the id of the product in the database.

This works ok except for one thing, if I use the modal close link ***data-dismiss="modal"*** to close the modal the next image i select keeps the existing id and i end up always seeing the first image selected.

To get around this, I am using a button that refreshes the page, but if I am viewing an image where i need to scroll thru the carousel this does not work as i lose the location of the image.

I have tried to reset the $_GET variable in the product_details.php file hoping this would help but to no avail.

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

[image: bootstrap-modal-thumbnails]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I end up adding when closing the modal

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '#myModal', function () {
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    $(this).find('.modal-body').html('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On the link with **data-dismiss="modal"** add

```
onclick="$('.modalBody').html('');"
```

Or, as people suggest, add this

```
$('#modal-item').on('hidden', function() {
  $(this).removeData('modal');
});
```

Comment: Didn't work, I end up with a blank modal when viewing the next item, I have found this page - http://www.whiletrue.it/how-to-update-the-content-of-a-modal-in-twitter-bootstrap/ , still trying to get it to fit into my situation

Apparently a know issue with bootstrap